# How to get the process name from dump file programmatically(IDebugClient) on Windows

Tags: kernel, symbols, windbg, dump, bsod

Using windbg, open the dump file and run '!analyze -v', there will be PROCESS_NAME property listed in the result, eg, PROCESS_NAME:  notmyfault64.exe.

But how to get the PROCESS_NAME by windows debugging API?

One possible way is using IDebugClient::OpenDumpFile() to open the dump file and then use IDebugControl::Execute() to execute '!analyze -v' and grab the PROCESS_NAME from the output. But it's looks like a workaround.

Is there any direct way to get the PROCESS_NAME via the debugging API? eg, IDebugSymbols3::GetModuleNames()?
I tried the code like this:

```
ULONG loaded = 0, unloaded = 0;
symbols->GetNumberModules(&loaded, &unloaded);
const ULONG count = loaded + unloaded;

DEBUG_MODULE_PARAMETERS* parameters = new DEBUG_MODULE_PARAMETERS[count];
symbols->GetModuleParameters(loaded, 0, NULL, parameters);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  symbols->GetModuleNames(DEBUG_ANY_ID, parameters[i].Base, ImageNameBuffer, MAX_PATH + 1, &ImageNameSize,
        ModuleNameBuffer, MAX_PATH + 1, &ModuleNameSize,
     LoadedImageNameBuffer, MAX_PATH + 1,
     &LoadedImageNameSize);

     std::cout << ImageNameBuffer<<", base level:"<<i << "\n";
  }
```

But how to decide which index or base should be for the module name?

And also there are some example here: https://medium.com/swlh/windows-debugger-api-the-end-of-versioned-structures-ac4acaa351bd , the question is also how to choose the correct process name to be the same with Windbg analyze result?

And so to the IMAGE_NAME and MODULE_NAME in windbg analyze result, how to get them by IDebugClient?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at/tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugsystemobjects2-getcurrentprocessexecutablename and alternatively, you can check the _PEB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugsystemobjects2-getcurrentprocesspeb So you'll have to initialize and use the COM object for IDebugSystemObjects2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The value is just 'srv*' when I tried the GetCurrentProcessExecutableName() API, which is not the expected "notmyfault64.exe"